# update MySql from Sql server with Special characters

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode

My Sql server SQL like this:

```
update mysqlEmp
set first_name=FirstName
FROM OPENQUERY(NTEMYSQL,'select * from data_source_db.employees') mysqlEmp 
INNER JOIN Employee on Employee.ID=mysqlEmp.id_number
WHERE CONVERT(date,Employee.Editdate) between '2018-09-19' AND '2018-09-26'
  AND (mysqlEmp.first_name!=Employee.FirstName)
  and employee.id='A0002779'
```

It will show errer:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NTEMYSQL" returned
>   message "Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been
>   changed since it was last read.". Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NTEMYSQL" could not
>   UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]". The rowset was using optimistic concurrency
>   and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row
>   was last fetched or resynchronized.

If I select the first_name using OPENQUERY (in sql server)

```
select first_name from OPENQUERY(NTEMYSQL,N'select * from 
data_source_db.employees') mysqlEmp 
where id_number='A0002779'
```

result : PHILIP NI?O

If I select the first_name in Mysql

```
select first_name from data_source_db.employees where id_number ='A0002779'
```

result :[image]

I think the Special characters [image] make my sql update errer

--Sql Server : column "FirstName" Type: nvarchar

--My sql: column "first_name" Type: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Those aren't special characters. It's just Unicode. `?` means the query tried to read *Unicode* as if it were ASCII. It's the *provider's* job to translate the character sets and codepages. When it fails, unrecognized characters are replaced by `?`. How was the linked server configured? Which provider did you use? Does it have settings that controll character set translation? MySQL has an [ANSI ODBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation.html) as well, which obviously can't handle Unicode

Comment: BTW your query reads *everything* from the MySQL database each time you run it, then tries to join with `Employee` without benefit of indexes. You could improve performance a *lot* by storing the data into a local table with indexes on the `id_number` and `first_name` tables. Another way to greatly improve performance is to load only the columns you need. Right now you are loading all columns but only using 2

Comment: Can you get the hex of the column?  `Ñ` is hex `D1` in latin1, hex `C391` in utf8, `U+00D1` in Unicode, etc.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored